# How to find original path of the uploaded image with Flask

Tags: python, image, flask

I want to find original path of the uploaded image but 'image_path' gives me the location of the project. Is it possible to save the path where the uploaded image is located?

```
def image_data():
data = {
    'full_image': request.files['image'],
    'image_name': request.files['image'].filename,
    'image_path': os.path.realpath(request.files['image'].filename)
}
return data
```

Comment: i tried abspath instead of realpath but it didnt help either

Answer (score 1):

As in the path of the user who uploaded the file? The file is uploaded, not the path of the user, also you wouldn't have much value in this information.

The path of the image is where it is currently stored for Flask, in the project, where the uploaded image file is probably located as well.